# Moving Files and Folders to another folder recursively

Tags: directory, copy

I am trying to move files and folders from one directory to other. Both of the files has multiple subfolders and files.

From the reasearch I have made it seems that the answer should be something like,

`cp mv -vr \Downloads\* .`

But I am not sure this is true or not. I am also not sure about using mv or copy. The files that I am copying have the same file names but the content is different.

Is this command correct ? Do I need '-v` argument ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no `cp mv` command. `cp` is used for copying and `mv` is another command that can be used to move a file or folder.
There is no `-r` option for `mv`. `mv` automatically moves all sub-folders and files to the specified path. But for `cp` you can use `-r` to copy directories recursively.
The `-v` option explains will explain what is being done (writes a log of moving ), so there is no difference between the move operation with and without the `-v` option.
If you try to copy or move files or folders to a path where other files and folders with the same name already exist, these commands overwrite the old files.
You can always see a manual of program by using the `man [the-program-name]` command.

Answer (score 2):

The "cp" command is meant to copy into a target directory. For "cp" the argument -v will print what the command is doing while doing it. Is short is the verbose argument. The argument -r, instead, is mandatory for a recursive copy. You can confirm it by running

```
cp --help
```

In general, you should use mv to move instead of cp by

```
mv name-of-folder/ path/to/move/
```

With the mv command, you don't actually need the argument -r. Instead, the argument "-v" has the same properties as in the cp command.

Generally speaking, anyway, in order to understand what an argument for a command is doing you can run

```
name-of-program --help
```

or

```
name-of-program -h
```

and look for the specific argument you want wandering. Usually, the basic commands are well-documented running -h or --help, and the name of the argument themselves are self-explanatory